# Passing data from one ViewController to another when switching tabBarController index instead of segueing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

My app contains a `tabBarController` with two tabs. Tab number `0` contains `SearchViewController`, tab number `1` contains `MatchCenterViewController`. What I want to do is set the value of `MatchCenterViewController`s `didAddNewItem` property before switching to that tab. I know that if I had done this with a segue, it would be done as so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowMatchCenterSegue"]) {
        MatchCenterViewController *controller = (MatchCenterViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;

        self.didAddNewItem = 1;
        controller.didAddNewItem = self.didAddNewItem;
    }
}
```

However I don't want to do this with a segue, I want it to simply set `didAddNewItem` of `MatchCenterViewController` before calling `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];`. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pull the view controller out of `[self.tabBarController viewControllers]`

A bit of pseudo-code for you to try and mess about with:

```
UIViewController *toViewController = [self.tabBarController viewControllers][1];
if ([toViewController isKindOfClass:[MatchCenterViewController class]]) { // This is just for the sake of safety. Good practice to get into type checking before you cast.
    MatchCenterViewController *matchViewController = (MatchCenterViewController *)toViewController;
    matchViewController.didAddNewItem = true; // Really this should be a Bool!
}
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to use a protocol and delegate, this is the cleanest way of passing this data to another view controller.  It also decouples your code to make it easier to manage later. For example you build an iPad version with no UITabbarController.

```
Define a protocol in SearchViewController.h:

//under the #import
@protocol SearchViewControllerDelegate

//define a property to send delegate messages to
@property (nonatomic,strong) id <SearchViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

//after @end
@protocol SearchViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)searchViewControllerDidSearchWithResult:(NSArray *)result;

Then when you are setting up the view controllers assign MatchViewController to be the SearchViewControllers delegate.

//in SearchViewController.m send the delegate message
[self.delegate searchViewControllerDidSearchWithResult:arr];

Then in MatchViewController adopt the protocol to get messages.
```